# What yeast for carbonating a lager?

Tags: yeast, carbonation, lager

We brewed a Dark Lager using Wyeast 2007. It fermented for two weeks and has been lagering for 3. When we bottle, we think  we'll need to repitch to ensure the bottles carbonate. Thoughts on what yeast to use? 
OG 1.06/FG 1.008

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience, you'll have more than enough yeast to carb.  I've lagered beer for 2-3 months and still had plenty.  If you really feel that you need to add yeast, any neutral yeast will be fine.  I tend to use US05 becasue it's inexpensive, easy and reliable.  You use so little that it has no effect on flavor, so you don't need a lager yeast.

Comment: Would I pitch that right before bottling or should I do so ahead of time?

Comment: Right before bottling.  Add it to the bucket with your priming sugar.  Go light, since you don't really need it anyway.